# VBA Code to Check one Column Data with Multiple Columns Data?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have id numbers on column **A** starts from **A3** To **A**25. I want to check each of the column **A** value with the **F** **G** **H** **I** columns values. In **F** **G** **H** **I** columns where data starts from 29th-row, how do check with **A** column value with multiple columns values at a time?

```
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow1 = Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   
    
For i = 3 To lastrow
 
    For j = 30 To lastrow1
 
        If Range("F" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value Or Range("G" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value Or Range("H" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value Or Range("I" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value Then
        End if

    Next j

Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code. i have tested on your query

Please test it if any problem, feel free to contact.

```
Function allvlookup(rng As Range, rng1 As Range)

    Dim rng_r As Range
    Dim str As String


    For Each rng_r In rng1
        If rng = rng_r Then
            result = rng_r.Value
        End If
    Next rng_r

    allvlookup = result

End Function
```